# Flutter desktop opens a new window

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-desktop, flutter-design

When clicking a button I want to open a separate new flutter window on my desktop flutter application. How can I do that? It must work separately.
My OS: Windows 10

Comment: Not supported yet, see the issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30701) but there's a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_window) which claims this multi-window functionality but every new window is a new app launch inducing the same delay that occurs when the app is launched.

Answer (score 2):

The Multi-Window project is on active development as of the moment. I don't think this will be supported soon since there are no official announcement yet. But if you are curious on what is the status of development, you can track it [here](https://github.com/orgs/flutter/projects/39/views/1). There is also an [open ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30701) in which this feature was being discussed. For now, I suggest you use [desktop_multi_window](https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_multi_window) plugin that could do this feature.

Answer (score 0):

you can use packages related to multi_window, if you are going for cross platform app i.e. win, mac, linux; check for multi platform support

- https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_multi_window